# Trying to Get the Most Cooling Power out of TEC Peltier Element: Smaller or Larger Peltier?

Tags: batteries, wire, peltier, cost

I am trying to achieve the strongest cooling effect using a TEC Peltier element.

- Currently, my set up is two small, 20mm x 20mm peltier TES1-4902 run with a 5V 2.4A USB Battery Pack per peltier.

**I need a way to reduce my costs while keeping the same cooling power.**

- Right now, it is expensive for me to run this set up due to the fact I need two batteries, and I am also looking to improve my efficiency **while cutting out an entire battery and/or Peltier.**
- The reason I have two separate battery packs is that I can not find a cheap, small, and thin battery pack that will output 4.8 Amps: **however, putting two battery packs in a series may help eliminate one peltier**.

**So, I have a few branching question that center around a theme:**

1) Would a larger Peltier allow for a stronger cooling effect as a result of a larger surface area, say like a 50MM x 50MM peltier, despite the fact (presumably) that it may be more difficult to cool one single peltier than 2 smaller, seperate ones?

2) Is there a Peltier size that would allow me to reduce my power consumption while maintaining a similar cooling effect?

3) Is there a way that I can output 5V 4.8A that is not in two separate USB battery packs that is small and relatively cheap, as battery price:output ability for small scale consumer is quite high and USB battery packs have been the cheapest source of sustainable power for me.

- My problem stems from the fact that I am trying to pump as much power and achieve as much cooling power as possible without having to have, say, two battery packs and make the project too expensive. **I need a way to reduce my costs while keeping the same cooling power.**

Comment: 1. Compare datasheets. 2. Compare more datasheets. 3. A sutable power supply.

Comment: @winny could you elaborate on that a little more? I am a novice.

Comment: In my answer to another TEC Peltier question I write about reading a typical Peltier junction datasheet. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/311252/35022

Comment: Thanks guys! Still need some more guidance though.

Comment: what delta T do you want/need?

Comment: @Neil_UK Hi Neil, I am not too concerned with minor differences in efficiency of my peltier as I need it to cool down as much as possible in the shortest amount of time, so I am pumping the maximum power I can get, 5V 2.4Amps, using  a very adequate heatsink. My problem stems from the fact that I am trying to pump as much power and achieve as much cooling power as possible without having to have, say, two battery packs and make the project too expensive. I need a way to reduce my costs while keeping the same cooling power.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that I am not shooting for a direct target, but the lowest temperatures using what I have available for the price range

Comment: in other words, a non-specification specification. I almost said 'don't say 'as much as possible''! Peltiers get hugely more efficient, not just slight differences, when under-run a little. Power required goes as square of dT, as square of heat pumped.

Comment: @Neil_UK Hey Neil, thank you for being patient as I really am a novice and I appreciate it. I am using a TES1-4902, and I know from your comment that I can run it more efficiently. How would I approach this? Do you have perhaps any recommendations on a specific Voltage/Amperage combination you think would work for me efficiently and effectiely? Thank you so much. I am willing to learn!

Comment: use the minimum current needed to get the dT, and increase the area/number of modules in parallel if you want to shift more heat, will give you the highest COP (coefficient of performance), a FOM (figure of merit) for cooling systems. Unfortunately, your dT budget has to include heatsink drops on both faces, and worst case ambient cooling. I've often played with using water cooling on the hot side, and then cooling the water with an evaporative 'bong' cooler, to get lower than ambient.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the datasheet, if you can't find it, have a look at the place you bought it from, see if they provide any information about the correct way and voltage to drive the Peltier module.

- The easiest way to check if a larger Peltier module will work better than two smaller ones is to check what wattage each small one is rated for and whether the larger one's wattage (50x50mm is usually 60w) is larger than the sum of the two smaller ones.
- If you have not already, add a heatsink, these things get really hot really fast, and you can damage them if you are not careful, if you add a fan to the heatsink, you will get even colder temperatures on the other side.
- I don't know about the size you have, but you need 12v 60w to power a 50x50mm Peltier module, as I mentioned earlier, double check if the voltage and current ratings are corre4ct for your module.
- If I might offer a suggestion, for prototyping, get a bench power supply, that plugs into the wall, if this is too expensive, you can always an old desktop/laptop power supply with a powerful buck-boost converter. This way, you won't have to waste money on batteries.
- It is also worth mentioning that Peltier modules are not very energy efficient, so unfortunately, you probably won't get the kind of cooling that you are hoping for.

Comment: Thanks Skillz, I have already constructed my prototype I just need a way to reduce costs: either by making a lower powered Peltier run better than what I have, or finding some cheaper battery alternative.

Comment: @Omar Sumadi What is the wattage of the two smaller Peltier modules?

Comment: TES1-4902 is the name! It's a pretty random peltier but I ran some really basic calculations and it worked with my set up. I am totally open to suggestions for peltiers/specific voltages/amperages or specific models that you think may run more efficiently as my selection I think is pretty arbitrary. I have to go to bed right now, but I seriously love anything you have to say!

Comment: @Omar Sumadi Then yes, a 50x50mm Peltier would be over two times more powerful, that is, if you can provide 12v at 5 amps... Your current solution for powering this will not work. Also, what is your application for this? It will help us understand the problem that you are facing.

Comment: Hey Skillz21, I am using the peltier with some other parts to cool water. I know I can probably find a peltier that is 40mm x 40mm at 12v 5 amps; however, I read two smaller peltiers are better than one larger one due to effective cooling rates. I have now been reading that I may not be running the peltier at the most efficient power settings: maybe this is a way to reduce costs.

Comment: I appreciate all the help; however, any help in regards to a cheap battery that can output 5v 4.8A is also appreciated over what I currently am using: USB battery packs.

Comment: @Omar Sumadi Ok, you have to be real, there is no way you are going to get a 5v battery that can output 4.8A for cheap. You would need something like the Anker PowerCore 20100, and that's about $40... You are not going to get a battery that powerful for cheap.